# What's wrong with this php-generated table?

Tags: php, html-table

I am trying to make a table via PHP, but when I load this, it displays it like this..

[image: printscreen]

The code:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
<?php
while($test= mysql_fetch_assoc($countquery)){
        echo '<tr><td>';
    echo $test["count"];
    echo 'x</td>';
};
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($topresult)) {
    echo '<td width="150">';
    echo $row["productnaam"];
    echo '</td><td width="100" style="text-align:center;">&euro; ';
    echo $row["prijs"];
    echo '</td><td width="50" style="text-align:center;">';
    echo '<a style="text-decoration:none;color:red;" href="#"><img width="25" src="trash.png"></a>';
    echo '</td></tr>';
};
?>
</table>
```

My goal is to display a table of 4 columns by 3 rows..

**EDIT:**
Found it already, it makes a new `<tr>` tag everytime the first `while` is performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block :

```
while($test= mysql_fetch_assoc($countquery)){
        echo '<tr><td>';
    echo $test["count"];
    echo 'x</td>';
};
```

will create 3 cells 1x, 1x, 2x first,
next the block:

```
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($topresult)) {
    echo '<td width="150">';
    echo $row["productnaam"];
    echo '</td><td width="100" style="text-align:center;">&euro; ';
    echo $row["prijs"];
    echo '</td><td width="50" style="text-align:center;">';
    echo '<a style="text-decoration:none;color:red;" href="#"><img width="25" src="trash.png"></a>';
    echo '</td></tr>';
};
```

will create cells from Monitor, so the result become like this.
To fix it, you should save the result from the first `while` loop to an array and go through at the 2nd `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing nested rows.

```
while($test= mysql_fetch_assoc($countquery)){
    echo '<tr><td>';// Here you open a row
echo $test["count"];
echo 'x</td>';//No closing of row, you close the td and open another tr on the next iteration
};
```